# Using a for loop (or iteration) within a map definition to be converted to JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-stream

I have the following code (not working) defining a map of lists which is being converted into a JSON...

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //Set pretty printing of json
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    //Define map which will be converted to JSON
    List<TimeSeriesRollup> dataPoints = null;
    for(int i=1; i<24; i++){
    Long xVal = graphs2.get(i).get(0);
    Long yVal = graphs2.get(i).get(1);
    dataPoints = Stream.of(
            new TimeSeriesRollup(xVal, yVal))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    List<TimeSeriesGraph> dataInfo = Stream.of(
            new TimeSeriesGraph("test", dataPoints))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


    //1. Convert List of Person objects to JSON
    String arrayToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataInfo);
    return arrayToJson;
```

the desired code functionality is something like this...

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //Set pretty printing of json
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    //Define map which will be converted to JSON
    List<TimeSeriesRollup> dataPoints = null;
    dataPoints = Stream.of(
            new TimeSeriesRollup(xVal1, yVal1))
            new TimeSeriesRollup(xVal2, yVal2))
            new TimeSeriesRollup(xVal3, yVal3))
            new TimeSeriesRollup(xVal, yVal))
            new TimeSeriesRollup(xVal, yVal))
            new TimeSeriesRollup(xVal, yVal)) etc...
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    List<TimeSeriesGraph> dataInfo = Stream.of(
            new TimeSeriesGraph("test", dataPoints))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


    //1. Convert List of Person objects to JSON
    String arrayToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataInfo);
    return arrayToJson;
```

I'd like to be able to add as many "TimeSeriesRollup"s as I'd like, defined by a variable somewhere else in the method. Any thoughts or insights on this? Any other info I can provide?

Comment: Doesn't that already work if you put commas between each `TimeSeriesRollup`?

Comment: Yeah. Both codes technically work, but i would like to use iteration instead of declaring 30 items. @DM

Comment: maybe check out the `java.util.stream.Stream.Builder` class?  The documentation says "This allows the creation of a Stream by generating elements individually and adding them to the Builder".

Comment: will check it out. thank you

Comment: What is `graphs2`?

Comment: graphs2 is a nested list in the form [[x,y][x,y]...] containing the data points i would like to graph @4castle

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, what you need is the index to compose the stream from a set of points, so you can start with an `Intstream` with the desired range:

```
List<TimeSeriesRollup> dataPoints =
                IntStream.range(0, 24)
                         .mapToObj(graph::get)
                         .map(point -> new TimeSeriesRollup(point.get(0), point.get(1)))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can give the `TimeSeriesRollup` class a static factory method with as input the `Point`, resulting in:

```
  IntStream.range(0, 24)
           .mapToObj(graph::get)
           .map(TimeSeriesRollup::from)
           .collect(toList());
```

Comment: or a constructor that takes the `Point` as input parameter, then change the mapping to `TimeSeriesRollup::new`

Comment: I will explore this option. Thanks!